# Firebase WEB - Email Verification not being sent. What's wrong with the code

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

Well, I've tried using many ways to trigger the function `sendEmailVerification()`. But none have worked successfully. The docs aren't helping either.

Below is part of the source code that I will be using. Please let me know of how I can correct this.

On my console I get the the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'emailVerified' of null
>            at Object.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged.firebaseUser [as next]

```
        btnSignUpWithGoogle.addEventListener('click', e => {
            var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

            firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            var user = result.user;
          }).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            var email = error.email;
            var credential = error.credential;
            console.log(errorCode);
          });
    });

    btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const email = txtEmail.value;
      const pass = txtPassword.value;
      const auth = firebase.auth();

      const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
      promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

      txtEmail.value = "";
      txtPassword.value = "";
    });

    btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const email = txtEmail.value;
      const pass = txtPassword.value;
      const auth = firebase.auth();

      const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
      promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

      txtEmail.value = "";
      txtPassword.value = "";

      const emailVerified = firebaseUser.emailVerified;

      if (!emailVerified){
        firebase.auth().firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().then(function(){
          alert('Please check your email to verify your Account.');
        });
      } else {
        alert('Your Email has been verified!');
      }

    });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
      if (firebaseUser) {
        console.log(firebaseUser);
        console.log('Logged IN!');
        btnLogout.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
      if (firebaseUser.emailVerified) {
        console.log('Email is verified');
      }
      else {
        console.log('Email is not verified');
        firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification();
      }

    });
```

Comment: if (firebaseUser.emailVerified) { should be changed to if (firebaseUser && firebaseUser.emailVerified) {

Answer (score 3):

Can we see all the code? Are you sure that your firebase.auth() is declared properly?

Your auth should look like this:

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'Client');
const firebaseAuth = firebaseApp.auth();
```

firebaseUser should have emailVerified key. Move your if else statement inside if firebaseUser like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
  if (firebaseUser) {
    console.log(firebaseUser);
    console.log('Logged IN!');
    btnLogout.style.visibility = 'visible';

    if (firebaseUser.emailVerified) {
      console.log('Email is verified');
    }
    else {
      console.log('Email is not verified');
      firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification();
    }

  }

});
```

`console.log(firebaseUser)`, what is says?

Answer (score 0):

sendEmailVerification() only works once you have the email address already loaded into firebase.

Check the below code : 
https://github.com/aqeelsmith/AngularJsData/blob/master/builds/angulardata/js/services/authentication.js - Line 82